# Git merge and ignore all CSV conflicts automatically

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I have two branches `brancha` and `branchb`. I have made some small code changes in `branchb` and have done a test run. As a result several CSV files have changed in `branchb`.

Now I am at `brancha` and I am trying to merge `branchb` with `brancha`. However I am getting several conflicts due to changed CSV files.

How can I ignore any CSV conflicts, i.e. take all CSV from `brancha` by default and only focus on code conflicts (if any) while merging `brancha` and `branchb`?

Answer (score 1):

After the conflict, you can do something like:

```
git checkout --ours path/to/directory/csv/*.csv
```

This command will resolve the conflicts accepting only the CSV changes from **ours** branch (the `brancha`, that is **receiving** the merge). As I put a wildcard to filter the CSV (`*.csv`), this will accept only the changes on CSV files.

If the CSV files are in different directories and/or you need a more complex filter for capture all CSV files changed, you can consult the [fnmatch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) documentation.